# Selecting/Highlighting Rows AND Changing Value of Highlighted Text Field in the Same Row

Tags: javascript, select, text, input, highlight

Long-time pilferer, first-time poster.

I'm attempting to create an interactive internet-based GUI with specific features that mimics the control panel of a product of one of my clients, but haven't had much luck getting it to do ***exactly*** what I want. I know the answer is out there. I will do my best to describe what I am trying to achieve, without getting too wordy. Really, though, checking out the fork just explains it best.

What I want to do is be able to have the user select rows on a display — in this case the "display" is being rendered as an unordered list — by using html/css buttons. In addition to that, I want them to be able to increase and decrease the value in the text box. Here's the kicker: I want them to be able to increase and decrease the values ONLY when the text box is highlighted. The issue I'm having is I can't get each of the text boxes to increase and decrease; I can only get the first one to change. Hopefully that explanation is clear enough, but please, check out the Plunker to get the best understanding. It will be much clearer when you see it live.

I've made many different drafts/versions of this and have tried using tables, but this has gotten me the closest. Now I just need to get over the hump. I'm completely open to doing this a different way, but it seems like this just needs a tweak here or there to get it going. I had an idea as I was creating this post that might work and doesn't involve a unordered list or list items, and gets "creative" with margins and padding to execute the highlighting. I haven't tried that yet, though.

I tried setting this up on jsfiddle, but something in the way my code is written doesn't jive with their software, so I tried Plunker and it seemed to work. Either way, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brettroby/f5jrL/, and here's the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BMSh19?p=preview. If someone wants to go to work on that fiddle and let me know why it's not working, that would be appreciated; however, the Plunker is working just fine as-is.

I also have one other issue that is minor and can be discussed after the main issue is resolved.

Thanks to all for the help!

PS — thanks to all the code writers out there whose code I borrowed to get this far. I'd be dead in the water without stackoverflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

#wrapper {
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #474747;
}

#screen-container {
float: left;
background: #6799ea;
width: 485px;
height: 300px;
border: 3px solid #efefef;
border-radius: 15px;
color: #ffffff;
}

#d-pad {
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 3px solid #efefef;
border-radius: 15px;
}

ul {
margin: 20px 10px 0 -30px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 50px;
}

li:selected {
color: #000;
}

#up {
position: absolute;
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
left: 120px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #efefef;
cursor: n-resize;
}

#up, #down, #left, #right {
text-align: center;
}

#down {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 120px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #efefef;
cursor: s-resize;
}

#left {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 110px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #b7d9ef;
cursor: w-resize;
}

#right {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 110px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #b7d9ef;
cursor: e-resize;
}

.number-input {
float: right;
width: 50px;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: right;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: 6799ea;
border: 0px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

a {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
// For: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=223429

var SBoxPtr = 0;
function SBoxPrevNext(amt) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('screen-container').getElementsByTagName('li');
  SBoxPtr += amt;
  if (SBoxPtr < 0) { SBoxPtr = 0; }
  if (SBoxPtr > sel.length-1) { SBoxPtr = sel.length-1; }
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    if (i == SBoxPtr) { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = 'cyan'; }
                 else { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = '6799ea'; }
  }
}
document.onkeyup = changeChars;


function changeChars(e) {
  var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;   //  alert(KeyID);
  if (KeyID == 187) { SBoxPrevNext(1); }    // Key '+'
  if (KeyID == 189) { SBoxPrevNext(-1); }   // Key '-'
  if (KeyID == 40) { SBoxPrevNext(1); }     // Key 'DownArrow'
  if (KeyID == 38) { SBoxPrevNext(-1); }    // Key 'UpArrow'
}

window.onload=function(){
SBoxPrevNext(0)
 document.getElementById("up").onclick=function(){SBoxPrevNext(-1)}
 document.getElementById("down").onclick=function(){SBoxPrevNext(1)}
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function decrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="screen-container">
<ul>
<li>Program Line 1 <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" id="number"></li>
<li>Program Line 2 <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0"></li>
<li>Program Line 3 <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0"></li>
<li>Program Line 4 <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0"></li>
<li>Program Line 5 <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" ></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="d-pad">
<div id="up"><p>&#9650</div><div id="down"><p>&#9660</div>
<div id="left" onclick="decrementValue()"><p style="">&#9668;</p></div><div id="right" onclick="incrementValue()"><p>&#9658;</div>
</div>

</div><!-- end wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to fixed your code, and you can see the correct plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDrmpW?p=preview)

The correction I have made are

Instead of:

```
function incrementValue()
{
   var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
   value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
   value++;
   document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

I have fixed it to:

```
function incrementValue()
{
   var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + SBoxPtr).value, 10);
   value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
   value++;
   document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value = value;
}
```

And also changed the elements name from number to numberX

Original

```
<li>Program Line 1
<input id="number" class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" ></li>
```

Fixed:

```
 <li>Program Line 1 
 <input id="number0" class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" </li>
```

Added id = number0 and numbered all other li's

if you find my answer helped you please mark it and press the UP key as well.
Thanks

Comment: Wow. That was fast...and amazing. You totally nailed it! I'm glad my demo was clear enough for you to take on and understand. Thanks a million. This will work perfectly. Now I am going to dress it up with images so that it looks like the "actual" control panel.

Comment: By the way, I can't press the up arrow on your suggestion/solution because I do not have enough reputation yet. Sorry. Hopefully someone else can come and do it for me (or an admin can authorize me to do it), because you solved my issue perfectly. I mean perfectly.

Comment: I now have one other issue to address. This deals with the styling of the text once it is highlighted. I could not get the highlighted text to change color. How do I do that? I messed with this part of the text: "if (i == SBoxPtr) { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = 'cyan'; }", but couldn't figure out how to add the additional markup. Any ideas?

Comment: Please answer as the one you accept
Regarding your last question I'll take a look tomorrow

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I'm still new to stackoverflow so I forgot to select the checkmark next to your post. All set now. I also have a couple more parts of this that I think might possibly higher on the priority list. I have updated the the Plunker here (http://plnkr.co/edit/Vqovs3?p=preview). If you look at the fourth option where it says "Pulse Mix", I would like it to cycle through a specific set of characters instead numbers; actually, I do not want a text field there at all. To make it simple what I'm trying to say, it could be something like "option1" "option2" "option3" and on and on...

Comment: If you have updated the Plunker then I suggest you open a new question in stack-overflow and show the problem in detail, it would be better and more readable to me and other users as well.

Comment: ...(continued) The options for that line actually need to be complete text phrases and not numbers, as there are no number options there; but I want the functionality to be the same as the ones above it where when you press the left or right arrow the value changes only when it is highlighted. I'm sure you can understand what I am saying. After that is sorted, I need them to be able to select the "more↓" option and then scroll down to a second screen, where it will be a new set of parameters that the users can adjust, just like the screen you see here on this demo.

Comment: As I already wrote, please open anew question and specify the new problem i.e. final result you want and what have you already tried.
This is StackOverflow site policy as well.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood what you were saying. It's all part of the same project and is related.