# Selecting/Highlighting Rows AND Changing Value of Highlighted Text Field in the Same Row (continued)

Tags: javascript, select, text, input, highlight

This is a continuation on the project from before, seen here ([Selecting/Highlighting Rows AND Changing Value of Highlighted Text Field in the Same Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974094/selecting-highlighting-rows-and-changing-value-of-highlighted-text-field-in-the)). User Scription has been incredibly helpful. Thank you!

The next line of business to get this working the way I need it to work is to have it so that the fourth option in the menu is editable via onClick, but in a way that is different from the options above it, as it requires a different set of options. The options for this line involve changing the text only, and does not involve numbers in any way. I have figured out how to change the text via onClick from another thread on stackoverflow, but I need to now integrate this into my existing design. I've got the Plunker going (link below). As you can see, I can get the fourth option row's text to change no problem by using the little button that I put down below the wrapper for testing purposes. I need this one to be able to be adjust ONLY when it is highlighted, and with the existing D-pad left/right arrows — the same way the other lines do. Obviously, the values need to increase and decrease according to which button is pressed, too. The text phrases start at one place and end in another, so the onClick events need to cycle through them in sequence.

To further complicate or add to the project, I need to be able to have the user scroll down to the "more↓" option and then into a completely new set/window of options. I would imagine we would use something along the lines of CSS overflow: property, but when combining it with all of this code I'm not really sure how to pull that off.

As always, any help is appreciated!

Plunk it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LarWS7qNrl0zXbRNaPS0?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

/* Colors for later: 6acff6 6799ea cyan */


body {
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.7em;
}

#wrapper {
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #474747;
}

#screen-container {
float: left;
background: #6acff6;
width: 485px;
height: 300px;
border: 3px solid #efefef;
border-radius: 15px;
color: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
}

#screen-container h1 {
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 100;
}

#d-pad {
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 3px solid #efefef;
border-radius: 15px;
}

ul {
margin: 5px 10px 0 -35px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

li:selected {
color: #000;
}

.number-input {
float: right;
width: 50px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 1em;
text-align: right;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

#up {
position: absolute;
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
left: 120px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #efefef;
cursor: n-resize;
}

#up, #down, #left, #right {
text-align: center;
font-size: .65em;
}

#down {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 120px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #efefef;
cursor: s-resize;
}

#left {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 110px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #b7d9ef;
cursor: w-resize;
}

#right {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 110px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #b7d9ef;
cursor: e-resize;
}

a {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
// For: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=223429

var SBoxPtr = 0;
function SBoxPrevNext(amt) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('screen-container').getElementsByTagName('li');
  SBoxPtr += amt;
  if (SBoxPtr < 0) { SBoxPtr = 0; }
  if (SBoxPtr > sel.length-1) { SBoxPtr = sel.length-1; }
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    if (i == SBoxPtr) { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = '0871b9'; }
                 else { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = '6acff6'; }
  }
}
document.onkeyup = changeChars;


function changeChars(e) {
  var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;   //  alert(KeyID);
  if (KeyID == 187) { SBoxPrevNext(1); }    // Key '+'
  if (KeyID == 189) { SBoxPrevNext(-1); }   // Key '-'
  if (KeyID == 40) { SBoxPrevNext(1); }     // Key 'DownArrow'
  if (KeyID == 38) { SBoxPrevNext(-1); }    // Key 'UpArrow'
}

window.onload=function(){
SBoxPrevNext(0)
 document.getElementById("up").onclick=function(){
   SBoxPrevNext(-1);
   };
 document.getElementById("down").onclick=function(){
   SBoxPrevNext(1);
   };
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + SBoxPtr).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value = value;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function decrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value = value;
}
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="screen-container">
<h1>Program Menu</h1>
<ul>
<li>Program Number <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" id="number0"></li>
<li>Etch Time Sec <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" id="number1"></li>
<li>Etch Temp &#176;C <input class="number-input" type="number" min="20" max="100" value="20" id="number2"></li>
<li id="program-type">Pulse HNO3 <!--<input class="number-input" type="text" min="0" max="80" value="3&#58;1" id="number3">--></li>
<li style="text-align: right">more &#8595;</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="d-pad">
<div id="up"><p>&#9650</div><div id="down"><p>&#9660</div>
<div id="left" onclick="decrementValue()"><p>&#9668;</p></div><div id="right" onclick="incrementValue()"><p>&#9658;</div>
</div>


</div><!-- end wrapper -->


<script type="text/javascript">
var nextWord = (function() {
  var wordArray = ['Pulse Mix N:S 6:1','Pulse Mix N:S 5:1','Pulse Mix N:S 4:1','Pulse Mix N:S 3:1','Pulse Mix N:S 2:1','Pulse Mix N:S 1:1','Vortex HNO3','Vortex Mix N:S 6:1','Vortex Mix N:S 5:1','Vortex Mix N:S 4:1','Vortex Mix N:S 3:1','Vortex Mix N:S 2:1','Vortex Mix N:S 1:1','Pulse H2SO4','Pulse Mix S:N 1:1','Pulse Mix S:N 2:1','Pulse Mix S:N 3:1','Pulse Mix S:N 4:1','Pulse Mix S:N 5:1','Pulse Mix S:N 6:1'];
  var count = -1;
  return function() {
    return wordArray[++count % wordArray.length];
  }
}());

</script>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('program-type').innerHTML = nextWord();">&#9658;</button>


</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE 2013-09-27**

I've updated my code and am getting close, but am stuck here: http://plnkr.co/edit/iZOJAx8BmKVMX8zII4kk?p=preview. I'm having a battle with that fourth row. It just doesn't quite work right. I can get the value to change and the proper text to display when I adjust the number with a keyboard, but it doesn't work with the onClick from the D-pad changes to the value. When the D-pad does it, no change to the text occurs. I think this has something to to with the "keyup" call in the code, but nothing I put in there (onBlur, onFocus, etc.) seems to work.

My current setup is far from elegant, so any suggestions on how to clean up that mess would be appreciated. I'm sure there's an easier way to accomplish the same thing, but this is what I conceived using the knowledge I have and the ideas that came to mind. Complete code can be seen below. Please pardon the relative links, as that was copied from my actual file (I'm starting to put together the interface now so I'm using graphics for many of the elements).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-collection.css">

<style type="text/css">

/* Colors for later: 6acff6 6799ea cyan */

body {
font-size: 1.7em;
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #6393c1 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#6393c1)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#6393c1 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#6393c1 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#6393c1 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#6393c1 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#6393c1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
font-size: 1.75em;
font-family: "alright-light","century gothic";
font-variant: small-caps;
font-weight: 100;
color: #427abd;
}

#wrapper {
width: 1150px;
height: 850px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #fafafa;
border: 1px solid #474747;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#keypad-body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1082px;
height: 670px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #b3b5b8;
border: 1px solid #474747;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#screen-container {
float: left;
margin: 90px 0 0 80px;
background: #6acff6;
width: 400px;
height: 220px;
border: 3px solid #d3d3d3;
border-radius: 15px;
color: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
}

#screen-container h1 {
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}

#d-pad {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin: 80px 100px 0 0;
width: 432px;
height: 336px;
background-color: #b3b5b8;
border: 0px solid #d3d3d3;
}

ul {
margin: 5px 10px 0 -35px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: .9em;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 32px;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

li:selected {
color: #000;
}

.number-input {
float: right;
width: 50px;
height: 30px;
font-size: 1em;
text-align: right;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

#up {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-button-up.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
margin: 30px 0 0 0;
left: 170px;
width: 90px;
height: 77px;
background-color: transparent;
cursor: n-resize;
}

#up, #down, #left, #right {
text-align: center;
font-size: .65em;
}

#down {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-button-down.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 170px;
width: 90px;
height: 77px;
background-color: transparent;
cursor: s-resize;
}

#left {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-button-minus.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: 130px;
width: 62px;
height: 64px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: transparent;
cursor: w-resize;
}

#right {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-button-plus.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 130px;
width: 62px;
height: 64px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #transparent;
cursor: e-resize;
}

#start {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-button-start.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 133px;
top: 140px;
width: 181px;
height: 54px;
background-color: #transparent;
cursor: e-resize;
text-align: center;
}

#stop {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-button-stop.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
float: right;
margin: 30px 100px 0 0;
width: 432px;
height: 66px;
border: 0px solid #d3d3d3;
background-color: transparent;
text-align: center;
}

#ntg-logo {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-ntg-logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 25px auto;
width: 320px;
height: 116px;
}

#jetetch-pro-logo {
background: url(images/keypad-graphic-jetetch-pro-logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: -70px 0 0 120px;
float: left;
width: 302px;
height: 151px;
}

#up, #down, #left, #right, #start, #stop {
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

a {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
}

input.button {
font-family: trajan;
width: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
border: 0px;
color: #4378bd;
background-color: #efefef;
font-size: .75em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 900;
}

input.button:hover {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #858585;
}

.button {
width: auto;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #4378bd;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: .6em;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}

</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// For: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=223429

var SBoxPtr = 0;
function SBoxPrevNext(amt) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('screen-container').getElementsByTagName('li');
  SBoxPtr += amt;
  if (SBoxPtr < 0) { SBoxPtr = 0; }
  if (SBoxPtr > sel.length-1) { SBoxPtr = sel.length-1; }
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    if (i == SBoxPtr) { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = '0871b9'; }
                 else { sel[i].style.backgroundColor = '6acff6'; }
  }
}
document.onkeyup = changeChars;


function changeChars(e) {
  var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;   //  alert(KeyID);
  if (KeyID == 187) { SBoxPrevNext(1); }    // Key '+'
  if (KeyID == 189) { SBoxPrevNext(-1); }   // Key '-'
  if (KeyID == 40) { SBoxPrevNext(1); }     // Key 'DownArrow'
  if (KeyID == 38) { SBoxPrevNext(-1); }    // Key 'UpArrow'
}

window.onload=function(){
SBoxPrevNext(0)
 document.getElementById("up").onclick=function(){
   SBoxPrevNext(-1);
   };
 document.getElementById("down").onclick=function(){
   SBoxPrevNext(1);
   };
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + SBoxPtr).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value = value;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function decrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number'+ SBoxPtr).value = value;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<h1>Virtual Keypad</h1>

<div id="keypad-body">

<div id="screen-container">
<h1>Program Menu</h1>
<form method="post" id="keypad">
<ul>
<li>Program Number <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" id="number0"></li>
<li>Etch Time Sec <input class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" id="number1"></li>
<li>Etch Temp &#176;C <input class="number-input" type="number" min="20" max="100" value="20" id="number2"></li>
<li><input class="number-input program-type" type="text" min="0" max="80" value="1" id="number3">
<span class="text0">Pulse HNO3</span>
<span class="text1">Pulse HNO3</span>
<span class="text2">Pulse Mix N:S 6:1</span>
<span class="text3">Pulse Mix N:S 5:1</span>
<span class="text4">Pulse Mix N:S 4:1</span>
<span class="text5">Pulse Mix N:S 3:1</span>
<span class="text6">Pulse Mix N:S 2:1</span>
<span class="text7">Pulse Mix N:S 1:1</span>help</li>
<li style="text-align: right">more &#8595;</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="d-pad">
<div id="up"></div><div id="down"></div>
<div id="left" onclick="decrementValue()"></p></div><div id="start"></div><div id="right" onclick="incrementValue()"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="stop"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('keypad').reset();"></a></div>
<div id="jetetch-pro-logo"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="ntg-logo"></div>

</div><!-- end keypad body -->

<center>
<br><br><form method="post">
<input class="button" type="button" value="Close Window"
onclick="window.close()">
</form>
</center>

</div><!-- end wrapper -->

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text0').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 0) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]>

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text1').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 1) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]>

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text2').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 2) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]> 

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text3').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 3) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]> 

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text4').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 4) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]> 

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text5').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 5) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]> 

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text6').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 6) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]> 

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var span = $('.text7').hide();

$('.program-type').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value == 7) {
       span.fadeIn();
   } else {
      span.fadeOut();   
   }

});

});//]]> 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: SO requires code in your question, not just on a 3rd-party site.

Comment: ↑ Thank you. The code is getting long so I didn't know what the etiquette is for situations like this where we've got so much. I will always post my code from here on out...

Comment: I have checked the example you created in plunker and everything seems to be working as expected, I was using chrome and fire fox
Which browser are you using?

Comment: I've tested on all of them: Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE. The issue is that in the fourth row — the one that says "help" — when you highlight that row and change the numbers, the event that I want to have happen does not happen. What should be happening is that text that says "help" should be cycling through other bits of text. If you put your mouse cursor in there, and then enter a number with your keyboard (be sure to use the numbers 1-7 for now), you will see how the text changes. This only happens when the text is changed via keyboard. I want it to happen when using the D-pad in the GUI.

Comment: I have did what you just described and it's working as you described
Pressing the D-PAD while on the HELP will change it's numbers as you described

Comment: I believe I am not being clear. Sorry about that. Changing the numbers is only part of what I want to have happen; ultimately, changing the text that is on that line is what should happen. If you put your mouse cursor in the number input box, then change the number using the keyboard, you will see what I mean. Insert a "5" just to see what I am talking about. The text that is on that line will change when you perform this with the keyboard, but it does not happen when you use the D-pad in the GUI. What I need to have happen is the changing of the text (for that line) when using the D-pad.

Comment: The best way for me to word it is this: as a user of the interface, scroll up and down using the D-pad exclusively. When you get to the fourth row, the + and - buttons should scroll through predefined blocks of text. Technically speaking, there shouldn't even be a text input box there, but I put it there to hopefully kickstart a train of thought. The way I am doing it now is probably "way wrong" but it's the best that I could do. I'm sure there's a much simpler solution than what I have conceived. I just need to be able to scroll through blocks of text rather than have an actual number change.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood what you mean.
in order to achieve that you have to add to each of the input boxes a new attribute

```
  onfocus="DoSomething()"
```

So that final result would look like

```
<input onfocus="FocusStripe(0)" class="number-input" type="number" min="0" max="80" value="0" id="number0" ">
```

While the number 0 suite for the first box, the number 1 suite for the second box and so on.

Then we have to write a new function as follows:

```
function FocusStripe(stripeID) {
   var sel = document.getElementById('screen-container').getElementsByTagName('li');
   sel[stripeID].style.backgroundColor = '0871b9';
   sel[SBoxPtr].style.backgroundColor = '6acff6';
   SBoxPtr = stripeID;
}
```

I have created a working plnker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nbTx5wfaqFDiRVk43Uf?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for working on this for me. I really appreciate it. I am still at a little bit of a loss, though. It doesn't seem to be working on my computer. It still works in the same way that it did before. How do I get it so that that text sentences cycle through? As it is now, the D-pad does not do this (in Safari and Chrome). The ideal scenario is that the number input field is not even there, as in the real interface there is no number. It is just several text options. I included the text options in my demo.

Comment: I threw together a quick Plunker so you can see what the + arrow should be doing: http://plnkr.co/edit/3GSVES63BsJUusfK1aMr?p=preview. I believe this helps illustrate what I would like to have happen. Of course, this should only happen when the row is highlighted. I just put this together so you could see the action.

Comment: if my previous answer helped you please mark it as helpful.
This is the best I can do right now.

Comment: It actually doesn't work. It's the same as it has been the while time. Did you see my question about how to get the text to actually cycle through? I think this is the key piece you might not be seeing. Anyway, I appreciate your time. If we could somehow hook up outside of stackoverflow I would love to get further help with this project and make it worth your while.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, However I do not have time right now for any other projects.
I would really appreciate it if you can mark my answer as an helpful one because I did invest time in it.